# EF SqlQuery throws not supported MultipleActiveResultSets exception if previous operation timeouts out

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, async-await

I have the following logic:

```
public async Task UpdateData(DbContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await LongUpdate(context);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($@"update d set d.UpdatedAt = GETDATE() from SomeTable d where id > 11");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
// this operations takes about 1 minute
private static async Task<int> LongUpdate(DbContext context)
{
    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 5; // change this to 15 to see MultipleActiveResultSets exception
    return await context.Database.SqlQuery<int>($@"update otherTable set UpdatedAt = GETDATE();SELECT @@ROWCOUNT").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

As presented above there are two update operations both awaited.
LongUpdate takes more than minute.

When timeout is set to 5s:
LongUpdate throws timeout exception and the second update is executed successfully.

**When I increase timeout to 15s or more:**
LongUpdate throws timeout exception but second update immediately throws: *System.InvalidOperationException: The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets..*

Shouldn’t await prevent this exception? 
Why this depends on timeout value?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Is it reproduced if you put `@"WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:59';select 1"` into `LongUpdate` instead of your `update otherTable set UpdatedAt = GETDATE();SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: @AlbertK thank you for comment. I checked WAITFOR DELAY - it does not produce MultipleActiveResultSets exception.

Comment: Additional finding: If in LongUpdate I use time consuming function which will update only couple thousands records problem does not appear. So I assume this only appears when big number of records is updated (millions).

Comment: Did you ever find out what it was?

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan this is simply misuse of EF/EF Core's DbContext. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connection. It's not meant to be accessed from multiple threads and doesn't need to. The `Database` property is a facade over the actual connection**(s)**. EF takes care to close and dispose connections immediately after use.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why is the connection is not opened and closed by EF in this situation? Side note: I am getting this error on different threads with different contexts few times a day. All operations are awaited. Granted it is as rare as 1 in millions of operations. But would be great to understand why. Perhaps starting with a simple case like this. I'm almost to the point of starting to look for the issue in the source code of EF. Granted it would be like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Comment: @g36 It might be an obvious question but did you specify this: `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` inside your connectionstring?

Comment: @PeterCsala Sorry, I don't want to specify "MultipleActiveResultSets=True". I am not using the MARS feature.

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan a better question would be why are you using such code? Why is the second query taking 15 seconds? Perhaps the only reason the code doesn't throw with a shorter timeout is that the query gets cancelled? How is this code called? If *that* query is still active after 15 seconds, did some other query try to use the same DbContext?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If we asked those question we would looking for a workaround... to what exactly? This is a Framework level question: after the timeout exception in LongUpdate, which is awaited, why does the second operation throw?

Answer (score 1):

According to EF docs `Database` property should not be used in a way you do. So because it is as i think incorrect way we could not even consider what is happenning. All you db operations should go via Database Context using `DbSet<T>` with `Save` or SaveAsync`method of`DbContext` call after changes in datasets. Of course you could execute raw sql but other way like this:

```cs
public static IList<StockQuote> GetLast(this DbSet<StockQuote> dataSet, int stockId)
{
    IList<StockQuote> lastQuote = dataSet.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM stockquote WHERE StockId = {0} ORDER BY Timestamp DESC LIMIT 1", new object[] { stockId })
                                         .ToList();
    return lastQuote;
}
```

To create DbContext (in below example to MySql) with command timeout you coulde use something like this:

```cs
public static class ServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureMySqlServerDbContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string connectionString,                                                                         
         ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, int timeout = 600)
            where TContext : DbContext
    {
        return serviceCollection.AddDbContext<TContext>(options => options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll)
                .UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
                .UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString), sqlOptions => sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(timeout))
                .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
    }
}
```

just call `services.ConfigureMySqlServerDbContext<ModelContext>(Settings.ConnectionString, loggerFactory);`

I think if you change your approach you get rid of exceptions.

Comment: You are talking about EF Core, while the original issue is with "classic" EF (EF6). These are completely different systems, hence none of your suggestions apply.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev i think even if original issue related with EF6 noneless this approach could be used with EF6 with a little differences in some details.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn’t `await` prevent this exception?

It depends on your **pattern**. We need to ensure that all access is **sequential**. In another word, the second asynchronous request on the same `DbContext` instance shouldn't start before the first request finishes (and that's the whole point). Although This is typically done by using the `await` keyword on each async operation, in some cases we may not achieve it. In your case, the first part of `LongUpdate` method execution, `context.Database.SqlQuery<int>()` is **not** an async method itself. It will provide results **synchronously** for `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. I think this is not a problem with EF async behavior.

> Why does it depend on the timeout value?

After a specific amount of time, the SQL query execution enters a **critical** state that can't leave it without spending more time than what you set as `CommandTimeout`, but your code moves forward and, the exception happens.

**Note** the applications that have IO-related contention will benefit the most from using asynchronous queries and save operations according to [Performance considerations for EF 4, 5, and 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/performance/perf-whitepaper#95-async). The page [EF async methods are slower than non-async](https://entityframework.net/why-ef-async-methods-are-slow) lists some noticeable points.

Answer (score 0):

The command timeout is distinct from the connection timeout. A value set with this API for the command timeout will override any value set in the connection string. [Database.CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.commandtimeout?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) Property is use for Gets or sets the timeout value, in seconds, for all context operations.

```cs
private static async Task<int> LongUpdate(DbContext context)
{
    context.Database.CommandTimeout = 5; // change this to 15 to see MultipleActiveResultSets exception
    return await context.Database.SqlQuery<int>($@"update otherTable set UpdatedAt = GETDATE();SELECT @@ROWCOUNT").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

here you set `CommandTimeout`, If your query not execute in 5 second then [TimeoutException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeoutexception?view=net-6.0) fired and after that you are trying to execute another query in catch block, but you use same `context` here, which is already timeout and its throws: `System.InvalidOperationException:`.
So to fix this you have to initialize your context again.

```cs
public async Task UpdateData(DbContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await LongUpdate(context);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            context = new MyContext()// initialize your DbContext here.
            await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync($@"update d set d.UpdatedAt = GETDATE() from SomeTable d where id > 11");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```